# Parsing .txt file in csv/xlsx in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, csv, xlrd

I am pretty new to python while trying out a scenario of parsing .txt file to csv/xlsx format I am facing below problem.

code to parse(html to txt) :

```
import requests as req
import re

resp = req.get("my_server_url")

content = resp.text

stripped = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', content)
with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
   print("Purchase Amount: {}".format(stripped), file=text_file)
print(stripped)
```

After parsing to text file I get the below output in .txt format :

```
Servicegroup 'app_service' Host State Breakdowns:


Host% Time Up% Time Down% Time Unreachable% Time Undetermined
sever1.domain.com:1717100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%   (0.000%)0.000%
sever2.domain.com:1717100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%  (0.000%)0.000%
sever3.domain.com:1717100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%
Average100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%


Servicegroup 'app_service' Service State Breakdowns:


HostService% Time OK% Time Warning% Time Unknown% Time Critical% Time  Undetermined
sever1.domain.com:1717app_availability_check0.000% (0.000%)0.000%    (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)100.000% (100.000%)0.000%
app_data_size_check0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)100.000%  (100.000%)0.000%
app_hitrate_check0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)100.000% (100.000%)0.000%
app_log_size_check0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)100.000% (100.000%)0.000%
app_sessions_check0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)100.000% (100.000%)0.000%
sever2.domain.com:1717app_availability_check100.000% (100.000%)0.000%    (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%
app_data_size_check100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%
app_hitrate_check100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%
app_log_size_check100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%
app_sessions_check100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%
sever3.domain.com:1717app_availability_check100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%
app_data_size_check100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%
app_hitrate_check100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%
app_log_size_check100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%
app_sessions_check100.000% (100.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000%
Average87.500% (87.500%)0.000% (0.000%)0.000% (0.000%)12.500% (12.500%)0.000%
```

from this output above I need to parse the same in excel with following values in respective columns

```
column 1               column 2       column 3                                      column 4
Host%                  Time Up%       HostService%                                  Time OK% 
sever1.domain.com:1717 100.000%       sever1.domain.com:1717app_availability_check  0.000%
sever2.domain.com:1717 100.000%       sever2.domain.com:1717app_availability_check  100.000%
sever3.domain.com:1717 100.000%       sever3.domain.com:1717app_availability_check  100.000%
```

Is there any way to get this specific data into csv/excel ?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use the csv module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: What can I acheive using csv module with this?
I have gone through the document I couldn't find any way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You need to do better data sanitizing or be more inclusive with your regex.

Generally you don't want to sub "something" for "nothing" when you still have processing to do. When you stripped out the HTML tags you were left with data that touches each other. Instead, you want to use a delimiter so you can break it down further later in the script.

Consider,

```
import string

DELIM = '||'

stripped = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', DELIM, content)
lines = []

for line in stripped.split():
    line = line.strip('|')

    # make sure it's an actual data line
    if line[0] in string.ascii_uppercase and line[-1] == '%':
        continue

    columns = [c.strip('%() ') for c in line.split(DELIM)]

    lines.append(columns)

..
..
# write lines to csv via `csv` module
```

Now, we can determine if each line is actual data since hostnames start lowercase and the last column is a percentage. Then, we can split each line again remove unnecessary characters from each column.

At the end we're left with a list of tuples where each element in the list is a row, and each element in a row is a cell.

It's important to remember `str.strip` will remove any of those characters in any order, as long as they're one of the outermost values.

```
x = 'abcdefg00001111!!'
print(x.strip('cab0!1'))
..
.. output:
defg
```

Comment: So shall I re -parse the data using the above concept you mentioned ? while parsing it to txt file from html?

Comment: I have tried the above code , It doesn't give the expected output as i require only the 4 columns of data that I have mentioned above.